# how can we upgrade our android device htc hero?

Tags: android

How can i upgrade my android device htc hero??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press on Menu , select Settings -> About phone -> System software updates, click on "Check now" , it shows if there is any updates for HTC Hero.

Depends on the Firmware (SDK Version) your HTC Hero is having, it will show the updates. I have updated the same phone from SDK firmware version 1.5 to 2.1 by using the above mentioned procedure.